# Django: relation between permissions and group

Tags: python, django

Why this works:

```
g = Group.objects.get(pk=1)
p = g.permissions.first()

Out[43]: <Permission: onboarding | controller | Can add controller>
```

But this doesn't work:

```
p.group
AttributeError: 'Permission' object has no attribute 'group'
```

When I do:

```
p._meta.__dict__
```

I see:

```
'fields_map': {'Group_permissions+': <ManyToOneRel: auth.group_permissions>,
  'group': <ManyToManyRel: auth.group>,
  'User_user_permissions+': <ManyToOneRel: core.user_user_permissions>,
  'user': <ManyToManyRel: core.user>}
```

So my question is, why can't I do `p.group` ?

Comment: Because it is a `ManyToManyRelation`. Hence i is `p.group_set.all()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [**`ManyToManyField`** relation <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) between `Group` and `Permission`. You can obtain the related `Group`s for a given `Permission` with:

```
p.group_set.all()
```